# How to transform one row into multiple columns in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have TABLE as a source with just 1 row, like this in Azure data factory with 336 columns:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 |

And a want to combine every 3 columns into the first 3:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| value4 | value5 | value6 |
| value7 | value8 | value9 |

What is the alternative to using Select on every 3 columns and then Join as it is long process with this many columns?

Comment: Is order important for you ? Do you have any primary key?

Comment: The values are generic double numbers...no primary key,I just want to combine every 3 columns into the first 3

Comment: I think you have good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your datasource is Azure SQL DB, you could conventional SQL to transform the row with a combination of UNVPIVOT, PIVOT and some of the ranking functions to help group the data.  A simple example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    col1    VARCHAR(10),
    col2    VARCHAR(10),
    col3    VARCHAR(10),
    col4    VARCHAR(10),
    col5    VARCHAR(10),
    col6    VARCHAR(10),
    col7    VARCHAR(10),
    col8    VARCHAR(10),
    col9    VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES ( 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8', 'value9' )



SELECT [1], [2], [0] AS [3]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        NTILE(3) OVER( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) nt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) % 3 groupNumber,
        newCol
    FROM #tmp
    UNPIVOT ( newCol for sourceCol In ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9 ) ) uvpt
    ) x
PIVOT ( MAX(newCol) For groupNumber In ( [1], [2], [0] ) ) pvt;
```

Tweak the `NTILE` value depending on the number of columns you have - it should be the total number of columns you have divided by 3.  For example if you have 300 columns, the `NTILE` value should be 100, if you have 336 columns it should be 112.  A bigger example with 336 columns is available [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/d71ae89e6812a990fe0a7eb181c3aa68).

Present the data to Azure Data Factory (ADF) either as a view or use the Query option in the Copy activity for example.

My results:

[image: results]

If you are using Azure Synapse Analytics then another fun way to approach this would be using Synapse Notebooks.  With just three lines of code, you can get the table from the dedicated SQL pool, unpivot all 336 columns using the `stack` function and write it back to the database.  This simple example is in Scala:

```
val df  = spark.read.synapsesql("someDb.dbo.pivotWorking")

val df2 = df.select( expr("stack(112, *)"))

// Write it back
df2.write.synapsesql("someDb.dbo.pivotWorking_after", Constants.INTERNAL)
```

I have to admire the simplicity of it.